# How to pull up to reload data in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here is my problem : I'm using nw.js and angularjs to write an desktop app.I want to realize pull up to load more data.

I use jquery to monitor the pull up event, and update an input.

html:

```
<input id="zs-scroll-input" ng-change="inputChange()" ng-model="scrollToBottom">
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
var nScrollHight = 0; 
var nScrollTop = 0;  
var nDivHight = $("#chat-window").height();
var count = 0;
$("#chat-window").scroll(function(){
    nScrollHight = $(this)[0].scrollHeight;
    nScrollTop = $(this)[0].scrollTop;
    if(nScrollTop + nDivHight >= nScrollHight)
    {
        count+=1;
        $("#zs-scroll-input").val(count);
    }
});
});
```

I tried to use ng-change to monitor the input change, so I can load more data in my controller.It seems if I change the input by hand, ng-change will be triggers.However changing it via jquery is not working.

Is there anyone know how to fix this?
Or what is the proper way to do scroll up to load in angularjs?

Comment: Don't use jquery in your angular code

Comment: @devqon so what is the right way to monitor pull up event?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $watch() to monitor changes.

```
scope.$watch('scrollToBottom', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  //do your work on change if newValue is different than oldvalue
  inputChange() // or something else
});
```

You can write this function inside controller that will work as document.ready.

And then you can change value in angularjs

```
$scope.scrollToBottom = count;
```

Comment: I tried, it worked when I change the input by my hand. Not working with changed by jquery.